# How to find standard deviation of image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

I have an image and I want to find the standard deviation for each row of the image and I will use the SD value for each row to calculate average SD of the image. I know the function to find SD (std) but I have no idea how to start/to do.

Answer (score 2):

Images in MATLAB are still just matrices.  Since you want to take the standard deviation for the rows, you can use `std(A,0,2)` to take the standard deviations along rows.  Then you can use `std` once more on the resulting vector to get what I think you are looking for.

Comment: I interpreted the OP as wanting the average row standard deviation , ie `mean(std(A,0,2))` - but I could be wrong. I certainly agree the intention is not very clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a greyscale image, use

```
mean(std(img.'))
```

If you have a color image (i.e., `ndims(img) == 3`), you'll have to repeat the above on each page of the array:

```
squeeze( mean(std(img,0,2)) )
```

which will result in the mean standard deviation of each row of each colour layer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the `std` of each row and then taking the mean, isn't it more accurate (and simpler) to just calculated the std of the entire image (all pixel values)? that is:

```
 std(img(:));
```

Taking the `std` of each row and then taking the mean is not exactly the `std` of all the pixel value of the image...
For example:

```
 >> a=peaks(100);
 >> mean(std(a.'))

 ans =

     1.4223

 >> std(a(:))

 ans =

     1.8882
```